# Accessing Masterpage from another folder in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'mm building an ASP.net site and I want to divide it into folder, but I want a masterpage in the main folder that everyone will access from anywhere  how do I tell a page that it's master page is in another folder?
(For example, think that I want my Login page within Users folder can access masterpage in main folder (Main folder > users))

Answer (score 0):

Set the path from the root folder of your web application to the desired master page file in the `MasterPageFile` attribute of the `@ Page` directive. For example if your web application is in folder C:\MyProjects\MyWebApplication (the folder where your `Web.config` is located) and your master page file `Bar.master` is located in the folder C:\MyProjects\MyWebApplication\Foo, then set `MasterPageFile` to "~/Foo/Bar.master".

Answer (score 0):

U can choose  master page at the time you create other pages.
so when you are creating the Login page choose master page from the Main folder

Comment: I built it not in visual studio that allows that. I'm building in WebMatrix